# React web is not working properly after build (related axios api)

Tags: reactjs, build, axios

I use 
"webpack": "3.8.1" , 
"react": "^16.5.2"

when start to yarn start app is working

but after the yarn build and serve -s build, not to call api. (but react-router is working)

In other words, it does not work for the http request. After the build

But as a yarn start, http request runs well.

(I use proxy in package.json. front-end is react, backend is spring boot)

Comment: are your http requests giving you 404s?

Comment: No, don't request at all, when read backend server log.

Comment: in your react app, do you have your requests written with the base url? Example: `http://localhost:5000/api/endpoint` or do you have it without base url like this, `/api/endpoint`?

Comment: I used axios like `/api/endpoint`

Answer (score 1):

I suspect your issue is like this. When you are developing you are using a proxy setup in your package.json as you have stated in your question.

When you have this proxy setting, webpack dev server will proxy your request from the client to the server. This is what allows you to leave the baseurl off your request in the app. In other words, because of this proxy you can simply write `/api/endpoint/`.

When you build and serve using the serve module however, webpack dev server is no longer the one serving your app the the browser, which means there is no more proxying requests from client to server. This means you are making a request to just `/api/endpoint/` which means there is no server actually getting your request.

Without actually changing your react code to use the full url including the base url in requests, you would need to actually have the server be responsible for serving the build folder to the web statically. By doing this, your `/api/endpoint` will point back the server that served the app which is also your api.

Comment: there are not requests in chorme network tab(to backend). i use axios in `componentDidMount`. but not working request when `serve -s build`. it is a problem with proxy?